# Building Spatialite network with long integer node?

Tags: spatialite, routing

After I build a spatialite network, I found that some node can't be routed. And after some survey, I found when the NodeFrom and NodeTo is bigger than **2^31 - 1**, it will return NULL.

Is there any solution I can build the network with large integer?

Comment: Bigger than 32768 as ten based? It does not feel like a big number at all. Perhaps there is something wrong with your graph. For compasison, select some OSM dataset from Geofabrik and create a graph with spatialite_osm_net https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite-tools/wiki?name=OSM+tools.

Comment: It was my mistake. it should be correct to "2^31 -1". For the regular number works fine to me. Only for these large integer I can't figure out how to route with spatialite. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like NodeFrom and NodeTo are using a regular (32-bit) integer datatype. If you change them to `bigint`'s (64-bit integer), you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes. After I trace the source code, I think I should modify the source code to use long integer type. Although I may need to modify many places, it looks like this is the only way to solve it.